# Consider tag which has attribute in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I want to search from xml which has section attribute
My controller code is:

```
xd.LoadXml(p.text);
XmlNodeList txt = xd.GetElementsByTagName("Texts");
for (int i = 0; i < txt.Count; i++)
{
    XmlNode nd = txt.Item(i);
    if (nd.HasChildNodes)
    {
        XmlNodeList cnd = nd.ChildNodes;
        foreach (XmlNode n in cnd)
        {
            if (SectionName == n.Attributes["section"].Value)
            {
                Text text = new Text()
                {
                    AudioList = n.Attributes["audio"].Value
                };
                newroom.text.Add(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and XML is like:

```
<Texts>
    <Text group="Outbuilding0">blank</Text>
    <Text group="Study0" audio="abc.wav" section="Walls and skirting">[[Walls and skirting]] </Text>
    <Text group="Study0" audio="c.wav" section="Walls and skirting">[[Walls and skirting]] </Text>
</Texts>
```

search start from only which has section attribute..any suggestion plz?

Comment: What's the `audio` attribute?  Those with `section` attributes in your sample don't have one.

Comment: I removed it..Now I updated @CharlesMager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to XML would make this a lot easier:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(p.text);

var texts = doc.Descendants("Text")
    .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("section") == SectionName)
    .Select(e => new Text
    {
        AudioList = (string)e.Attribute("audio")
    });

foreach (var text in texts)
{
    newroom.text.Add(text);
}
```

It is perhaps more readable in query syntax:

```
var texts = from text in doc.Descendants("Text")
            let section = (string)text.Attribute("section")
            where section == SectionName
            select new Text
            {
                AudioList = (string)text.Attribute("audio")
            };
```

Comment: One last question: If I want to search `audiopath` from another xml which has same name as `AudioList`

Comment: You would need to load that XML and search it in a similar way.  If you have any specific issues with doing that after trying it make make sense to ask a new question.

Comment: I am trying with same thing..but not getting any idea how to access `audiolist` in where condition

Comment: It would be hard to suggest how as I've not seen the XML.   If it is an attribute, then the `where` part would be similar to above.

Comment: XML IS LIKE:  <Audios><Audio group="Front0">
    <File_name>2013042517364073_Front0_1.wav</File_name>
    <Path>/Job_Files/74/1_Front0/Audio/2013042517364073_Front0_1.wav</Path>
    <Size>169</Size>
    <Audio_length>00:00:21</Audio_length>
  </Audio></Audios> Just want to compare audiolist with filename

Comment: I presume it `audio` attribute matches the `Path` element?  So something like `doc.Descendants("Audio").Single(e => (string)e.Element("Path") == "path-here")` would find you the relevant `Audio` element.

Comment: ` == "path-here")` name is same like `audiolist` so there is no need to use of audiolist over there? this is not static path

Comment: That's where you'd pass in the value for the path.  This isn't the ideal medium for asking a secondary question - if you're still having issues with this I'd suggest creating a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `SelectNodes()` passing suitable [xpath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as parameter :

```
XmlNodeList txt = xd.SelectNodes("//Texts/Text[@section]");
foreach(XmlNode t in txt)
{
    Text text = new Text()
    {
        AudioList = t.Attributes["audio"].Value
    };
    newroom.text.Add(text);
}
```

Above xpath reads: select all `<Text>` having attribute `section` and is direct child of `<Texts>`.

Comment: SORRY..your code is not giving any output..shows null in txt

Comment: Something must be wrong. `SelectNodes()` should've returned some result, see the demo : https://dotnetfiddle.net/KLkRSC